# Better way to pass variables?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have form which generates content in a textarea box, and currently I'm passing the forms options as following:

```
function button_click() {
    var columns = $('#form_id').val();
    var url='generate.php?';        
    url+='&form_id='+encodeURIComponent(form_id);
    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json; charset=x-user-defined");
    }
    })
```

Then on the php page I have a request:

```
$form_id= $_REQUEST['form_id'];
```

Then I can use the variable how I wish in php.

It seems a bit redundant.

How can I condense this, if I make the form all php instead of using all ajax/json would that make a big difference?

Comment: you can use the shorthands for ajax post/get like:
$.get('generate.php', $('form#your-form-id').serialize(), function(o){}, 'json');
Same goes for $.post();
This will save you of typing allot of text.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question correctly I would say that it is impossible to do what you want. The problem is that PHP script is executed on the server side, and javascript and form are handled by client side (browser).

So in general there is no way to get direct access from PHP to variables (elements) of your form/javascript. You can only pass these variables from the form by GET/POST HTTP request to server where you can handle them by your PHP script.